# Populate ID across specific columns from the comment sections

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have some data where the organisms ID was populated in the comment section. For example an ID looks like "2022-05-04-wood-pscr1". That ID can be traced to various swabs conducted on the animal. I need to move the one swab ids out of the "capture_comments" and have that same swab_id appear across all the differenet swab_id columns (bd_swab_tube_id, dry_swab_tube_id, crispr_swab_tube_id, bacterial_swab_tube_id, mucusome_id, amp_id_1, antibody_id_1, toe_clip_tube_id).

So that single ID present in the "capture_comments" column needs to be pasted into each of these columns while remaining at the same row level.

Not fully sure how to reproducibly make this maneuver.

Here is the sample data

```
data <- structure(list(species_capture = c("Pseudacris crucifer", "Rana catesbeiana", 
"Pseudacris crucifer", "Rana catesbeiana", "Rana clamitans", 
"Rana catesbeiana"), body_mass = c(1.6, 13.1, 1.4, 10.1, 4.9, 
12.3), bd_swab_tube_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), dry_swab_tube_id = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), crispr_swab_tube_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), bacterial_swab_tube_id = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), mucusome_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), amp_id_1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), amp_id_2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), amp_id_3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), amp_id_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), antibody_id_1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), antibody_id_2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), antibody_id_3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), antibody_id_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), toe_clip_tube_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), capture_comments = c("2022-05-04-wood-pscr1", 
"2022-05-04 wood racl #2", "2022-05-04 wood pscr #3", "2022-05-04 wood raca #4", 
"2022-05-04 wood racl #5", "2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

A sample of what I mean by the IDs from the capture_comments going into the columns

| dry_swab_tube_id | mucusome_id | capture_comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-04-wood-pscr1 | 2022-05-04-wood-pscr1 | 2022-05-04-wood-pscr1 |
| 2022-05-04 wood pscr #3 | 2022-05-04 wood pscr #3 | 2022-05-04 wood pscr #3 |

Comment: Please save the `rstudio` tag for issues where RStudio is part of the problem - like if your code works in the default RGui but doesn't work in RStudio.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: @GregorThomas got it, sorry about that

Comment: Also, if you could share a more minimal data set, that would help things be clear. Could this problem be demonstrated on 8 columns instead of 36?

Comment: sample of results and better dput has been updated

Comment: @Jake your updated data shows 17 columns, why you are selecting only 3 columns in expected output.  It is not clear about the expected.  Are you trying to replace the NA with the same row value of capture_comments?

Comment: In my post I state that I need to move the swab id from the capture_comments (2022-05-04-wood-pscr1) and place them in all the "_id" columns. So the strings in the "capture_comments" need to be moved to all "_id" columns. And yes there is 7 "_id" columns in which the string from the "capture_comments" needs to be maintained per row

Comment: @Jake it is not clear.  May be `data %>% mutate(across(ends_with("_id"),  ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), capture_comments)))`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(species_capture, capture_comments, body_mass), ~coalesce(., capture_comments)))
```

```
 species_capture     body_mass bd_swab_tube_id           dry_swab_tube_id          crispr_swab_tube_id       bacterial_swab_tube_id    mucusome_id               amp_id_1             amp_i…¹ amp_i…² amp_i…³ antib…⁴ antib…⁵ antib…⁶ antib…⁷ toe_c…⁸ captu…⁹
  <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>                <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Pseudacris crucifer       1.6 2022-05-04-wood-pscr1     2022-05-04-wood-pscr1     2022-05-04-wood-pscr1     2022-05-04-wood-pscr1     2022-05-04-wood-pscr1     2022-05-04-wood-psc… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
2 Rana catesbeiana         13.1 2022-05-04 wood racl #2   2022-05-04 wood racl #2   2022-05-04 wood racl #2   2022-05-04 wood racl #2   2022-05-04 wood racl #2   2022-05-04 wood rac… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
3 Pseudacris crucifer       1.4 2022-05-04 wood pscr #3   2022-05-04 wood pscr #3   2022-05-04 wood pscr #3   2022-05-04 wood pscr #3   2022-05-04 wood pscr #3   2022-05-04 wood psc… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
4 Rana catesbeiana         10.1 2022-05-04 wood raca #4   2022-05-04 wood raca #4   2022-05-04 wood raca #4   2022-05-04 wood raca #4   2022-05-04 wood raca #4   2022-05-04 wood rac… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
5 Rana clamitans            4.9 2022-05-04 wood racl #5   2022-05-04 wood racl #5   2022-05-04 wood racl #5   2022-05-04 wood racl #5   2022-05-04 wood racl #5   2022-05-04 wood rac… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
6 Rana catesbeiana         12.3 2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1 2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1 2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1 2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1 2022-05-05 Phelps raca #1 2022-05-05 Phelps r… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0… 2022-0…
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​amp_id_2, ²​amp_id_3, ³​amp_id_4, ⁴​antibody_id_1, ⁵​antibody_id_2, ⁶​antibody_id_3, ⁷​antibody_id_4, ⁸​toe_clip_tube_id, ⁹​capture_comments
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("_id"), 
        ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), capture_comments)))
```

Comment: @Jake You have also columns like `"amp_id_1"`, `"amp_id_2"`, etc.  . which I was not sure whether it needs to change. If you need to change the 'id' columns, chan ge the ends_with to `contains("id")`

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Thank you so much for the help and your patiences